# Variables in Select Statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following function:

```
    public List<TopMediansModel> QueryForMedians(string state, string median)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        return (from q in db.StateSuburbLocation
                where (q.State == state)
                orderby q.GetType().GetProperty(median) descending
                select new TopMediansModel
                {
                    Median = median,
                    MedianValue = q.GetType().GetProperty(median),
                    MedianSuburb = q.Suburb
                }).Take(10).ToList();
    }
```

Is it possible to have the `orderby` and `MedianValue` 'properties' as variables?

I've tried using the `GetType().GetProperty()` Methods, and am no doubt doing so incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like [Dynamic Linq](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/documentation)

```
return db.StateSuburbLocation
         .Where(l => l.State == state)
         .OrderByDescending(median)
         .Select(l => new TopMediansModel {
             Median = median,
             MedianValue = q.GetType().GetProperty(median),
             MedianSuburb = q.Suburb
          }).Take(10).ToList();
```

Or you can build query expression manually

```
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderByDescending<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName)
    {         
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);
        var keySelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(property, parameter);
        return source.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
    }
```

Usage is same

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Sergey, I'd prefer not to use another reference as I'll only be doing this in one function. Could you explain what you mean by building the query expression manually?

Comment: Trying this I get the following error `Error 1 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderByDescending<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`